# OpenGL instanced drawing how to deal with vertex input limitation

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I'd like to implement instanced rendering to my opengl engine but I've just learned that the maximum number of inputs supported by vertex shader is only 16 for my GPU.

These are the following matrices I need to move to input:

```
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 DepthBiasMVP;
```

If I understand correctly I will need an attribute for every column of each matrix, so I'll need 4+4+3+4 = 15 attribute space. 19 with the attributes that I already use ( pos, color, texCoord, normal ), and it  will grow up to 20+ if I add tangents and other stuff.

Is there a way to deal with this or will I have to forget the instanced drawing ? Let's say I managed to get rid of one of these matrices (modelMatrix) and I have about 15 - 16  attributes, will it work on different GPU's ? the 16 limit is the minimum for all GPU's right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 16 is the **minimum** amount of vertex attributes that your implementation actually has; most of the time more are allowed that you can query via:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &n).
```

Now, when trying to store all your data in *instanced arrays* you should try and organize what the data actually is that you want to differ per instance. Do you have a lot of instanced objects that only differ in location and/or orientation? Then you probably **only** need to set your `uniform modelMatrix` as an instanced array (which requires 4 vertex attributes, an acceptable value). Do you really need a different view and projection matrix for each instance? Probably not. The same holds for `DepthBiasMVP`.

The `normalMatrix` is required if you perform non-uniform scaling and if you plan to do that for each instance you also need to set a `normalMatrix` per instance. You could calculate those on the CPU beforehand and send them as vertex attributes costing you another 4 vertex attributes. Another option is to calculate `normalMatrix` in the vertex shader, but that this might slow your vertex shader down a little (perhaps an acceptable tradeoff?).

These should reduce the information you need per instance to just the `modelMatrix` and perhaps the `normalMatrix`, already reducing it by half. Maybe you only have a different position per instance? In that case even a simple `vec4` will do.

Basically, try to think about what data you **actually** need to update per instance and you'll most likely be surprised as to how much data you actually need for each instance.

Answer (score 2):

One can store the per-instance data in uniform arrays, [uniform buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [texture buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) and use the `gl_InstanceID` variable in GLSL to access the data in the buffer object. Uniform arrays might seem the easiest, but are most limited in size and hence are only applicable for a low number of instances. UBOs can be a bit bigger, but are also quite limited. TBOs on the other hand will allow you many megabytes of data, but you have to appropriately pack your data there. In your case, it seems that you only need float types, so a base format with 32 bit floats should suffice.